# BTS.SendPortTransformHint

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

What is the above property for and how to set it? I have researched Google, but all I got was the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bts.sendporttransformhint%28BTS.10%29.aspx) documentation for the corresponding .NET class, which doesn't have any useful information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use this promoted property to set the 'Outbound Map' of a **Dynamic** send port.

You need to supply a fully qualified type name (the string containing 'type,assembly,Version,Culture,PublicKeyToken') of the BizTalk map to be applied to the outgoing message at the end of send port processing.

Comment: Have had a play around with the SendPortTransformHint.  The property is being set correctly in the Orchestration, but appears to be ignored at execution time by the Dynamic Send Port.
Next step would be to have a look in the Send Port code using Reflector, to see what it is meant to do with the promoted property.